# android quickBlox Video calling code force close on click on receive button click

Tags: android, video, call, quickblox

Hello all i need to integrate video and audio call using QuickBlox

for that i am using [This link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android)

i am able to login with user name and password

But when user clickes on receive video call they get error and force close app on both the device

the error is

```
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-39405
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): Process: com.quickblox.videochatsample, PID: 3104
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ilbc-codec from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quickblox.videochatsample-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.quickblox.videochatsample-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<init>(Codec.java:16)
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:5)
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.quickblox.videochat.core.objects.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.run(AudioRecorder.java:196)
02-03 18:04:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: did  you add the `.so` files in lib folder ?

Comment: no there not any .so file i have please give link

Comment: there are `.so` files. https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi

Comment: yes that file is available in jniLibs i now puted it in my libs folder like that?

Comment: create a folder in `libs` and paste `armeabi` folder in that

Comment: ok trying that  please wait

Comment: ok done that... Thaks a lot thanks.... if it possible to voice call only?

Comment: Glad I can help. I am posting it as an asnwer, accept upvote if helped

Comment: yes of course but it is also for voice calling?

Comment: you have to check the documentation for that.

Comment: and for group video calling?

Comment: these files are basically codec drivers. So may they are not needed if they are using the default for Voice

Comment: If the Group chat is supported then Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error indicates that lib files are missing. There are `.SO` files for codec which should be in the project.

As you mentioned QuickBlox link, copy [these files](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi) into your `libs/armeabi` folder